# Suma de cinco valores

Tags: php

Estoy intentando hacer la suma y no sé cual es la forma más efectiva de sumar cinco valores que próximamente serán más la más simple es `$Datos[0]["Valor"]+$Datos[1]["Valor"]...` pero sería la más sucia por así decirlo.

He pensado en while o for pero no sé como meter al syntaxis de suma para que directamente lo sume ya que seria `$Datos[$i]["Valor"]` pero me saca los valores por separado sin sumar.

Estoy usando a lo brusco `$C1 = $Datos[0]["Caida1"]+$Datos[1]["Caida1"]+$Datos[2]["Caida1"]+$Datos[3]["Caida1"]+$Datos[4]["Caida1"];` He intentado con `for ($i = 0, $j = 0; $i <= 4; $j += $i, print $i, $i++);` pero no se como meter la suma ahí

Comment: Puedes subir el código que llevas?

Comment: Estoy usando a lo brusco $C1 = $Datos[0]["Caida1"]+$Datos[1]["Caida1"]+$Datos[2]["Caida1"]+$Datos[3]["Caida1"]+$Datos[4]["Caida1"];

He intentado con for ($i = 0, $j = 0; $i <= 4; $j += $i, print $i, $i++); pero no se como meter la suma ahí.

Comment: Empieza a leer por aqui y cuentanos lo que has intentado:http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-sum.php

Comment: Eso estuve haciendo pero se ve que lo hacia mal al poner la variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con un ciclo for, puedes sumar así:

```
$suma = 0; // Aquí guardamos la suma
for ($i = 0; $i < count($Datos); $i++) {
    $suma += $Datos[$i]["Caida1"]; // ó $Datos[$i]["Valor"]
    // $suma = $suma + $Datos[$i]["Caida1"]; // Es lo mismo
}
```

Luego el resultado de la suma la tendríamos en `$suma`.

Comment: Así es como lo estaba intentado hacer  pero ne vez de hacerlo dentro lo ponía por separado y entonces me salia los valores por separado fallo mio ahí lo delimite con <= 5; y perfecto.

Comment: Solo una recomendación, es menos costoso asignar el valor de count a una variable que realizar un count  cada vez que se compruebe la condición: lo mejor sería hacer algo así en el for: `for ($i=0, $count=count($Datos); $i < $count; $i++) {}`

Answer (score 0):

Haz uso del método `array_sum()` que te pedirá un arreglo de valores para sumar, como puedes notar aunque de manera explícita no hago un uso de un for o algún otro bucle, el método `array_sum()` si lo hace puesto que itera o recorre cada uno de los elementos que componen al arreglo; entonces puedes replenatear tu código de la manera siguiente

```
<?php


$numeros = array(
                    $num1 = 90,
                    $num2 = 50,
                    $num3 = 50,
                    $num4 = 40,
                    $num5 = 30
                );


echo array_sum($numeros);
```

Comment: Ese también lo vi pero tenia que hacerle un bucle de igual modo a la variable.

Comment: esta bien, que bueno que encontraste la respuesta @Vicente saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo de igual modo tu respuesta iba bien encaminada por eso también lo pusé a prueba antes de consultar dado que un for o while era lo más acertado pero lo iba poniendo mal y me daba los valores por separado.